# Подключение JQuery. Не получается подключить

Tags: javascript, jquery, webstorm

Всем доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, не понимаю в чем дело, пытаюсь подключить JQuery в WebStorm, вставляю ссылку на CDN, WebStorm подчеркивает, как ошибку, библиотека не подключается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Скачал js файл, для подключение, добавляю его, все равно подчеркивает как ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знаю, можно установить через npm или bower, но хотелось бы понять почему именно так не получается. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

https://dropmefiles.com/3KghE ссылка на исходник. Через bower установил, но почему то тоже не заработало

Comment: добавьте исходник целиком

Comment: А что пишет то, когда подчеркивает?

Comment: В первом случае  statement expected
Во втором случае Expecting newline or semicolon (в ожидании новой строки или точки с запятой)

Comment: У вас скорее всего где-то в этом файле отсутствуют кавычки где-нибудь. Прогоните через онлайн валидатор весь файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас настроен [language injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-language-injections.html) в `<script src` атрибут, поэтому WebStorm пытается распарсить его значение по правилам соответствующего языка (JavaScript?) и выдает синтаксические ошибки. Пожалуйста, откройте закладку **Settings | Editor | Language Injections** и найдите там все инжекшены, у которых **Scope** не *Built-in* (*IDE, Project*, etc.) и удалите или отключите их